# Fix/consume invalid JSON numbers with leading zeros (0's)? e.g. "03"

Tags: ruby, regex, json, parsing, nokogiri

I have a JSON string which I was able to scrape from a website. I only needed the following data (the original string is much longer)  Here is the retrieved JSON which I am planning to convert into a Ruby Hash:

```
{"day": 15, "month": 03, "year": 2012, "hour": 10, "min": 00, "sec": 00}
```

I retrieved the above json by using the regex:

```
targetDate:\s+(.*?)}\)/m
```

I am not able to parse the above json because of the extra zeroes in the integers. (00 and 03)
I tried changing the numbers manually using 3 instead of 03 and 0 instead of 00 and it worked!

So, I guess that the json parser may not be able to look at that kind of number.

The question is, how do I clean the retrieved JSON above so as to remove the unnecessary zeroes.  That is,

```
{"day": 15, "month": 3, "year": 2012, "hour": 10, "min": 0, "sec": 0}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: This is the error message when I try to parse it: _710: unexpected token at '{"day": 15, "month": 03, "year": 2012, "hour": 10, "min": 00, "sec": 00}'_

Comment: You are correct. I forgot JSON *forbade* numbers (except 0.xyz) begin with zero.

Comment: Minor correction: JSON Forbids any number except *`0` itself* and `0.xyz` to begin with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than bring in regex, maybe just eval it:

```
hash = eval '{"day": 15, "month": 03, "year": 2012, "hour": 10, "min": 00, "sec": 00}'.gsub(': ', ' => ')
```

Comment: Hey! It's you again! Your answer does work after testing it. Much simpler and cleaner! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't do it that way if there might be malicious code in there though.

Comment: It's okay. I'll just be using this for practice's sake. But as I have been reading, they say it is not a generally good idea to use eval.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp

```
json = '{"day": 15, "month": 03, "year": 2012, "hour": 10, "min": 00, "sec": 00}'
json.gsub(/\b0*(\d+)/, '\1')
#=> {"day": 15, "month": 3, "year": 2012, "hour": 10, "min": 0, "sec": 0}
```

**EDIT:**

Although not strictly necessary (see comments), the `\b` word boundary ensures that only zeros at the start of a number can be matched.

Comment: Will change `"year": 2012` into `"year": 212` and remove all but last zeroes from all numbers

Comment: @kirilloid: I had thought so, too, but actually it doesn't do this. When matching `2012`, the `0*` part looks at the `2` and fails, so `\d+` matches `2012` and all is well. But I would make it explicit by adding a `\b` word boundary at the start regardless since this is somewhat counterintuitive.

Comment: Thanks for this. It actually worked. `test = JSON.parse('{"day": 15, "month": 03, "year": 2012, "hour": 10, "min": 00, "sec": 00}'.gsub(/0*(\d+)/, '\1')) # => test['year'] gives 2012

Comment: @TimPietzcker, I think you are right. I'll try to make my version more intuitive and post it back here. Thanks!

Comment: @TimPietzcker Hmm. This really works ok. I still could provide a *bad* example: `{"phone-number":"123-05-07"}`

Comment: @kirilloid: Word boundaries wouldn't help here either.

Comment: Guys, check out @pguardiario's answer. It does not involve regex.

Comment: @nmenego http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902744/when-is-eval-in-ruby-justified

Answer (score 0):

```
json.gsub(/(?<=[: ])0+(\d+,)/, "\\1")
```

Keep in mind, that you may have json like `{ "someKey": "james bond: 007" }`, which will be replaced to `{ "someKey": "james bond: 7" }`.

```
json.gsub(/("\w")\s+:\s+0+(\d+)\s+,/, "\\1: \\2,")
```

is looking better, but it possible to "outsmart" this regexp too.
Regexp aren't well-suited for such problems.

Ok, here're non-regexp solution:

```
var inString = false; # check, whether current char is in string. Think of it as whether current symbol would be highlighted as string constant in editor
var out = []; # array/stack for output
var prevChar = null; # previous char. One may init to space symbol or even replace it with `out[-1]` everywhere
for (chr in jsonStr) { # iterate over symbols (chars) of a string
    if (char == '"' && prevChar != "\\") inString = !inString;
    if (!isDigit(out[-2])
    &&  prevChar == '0'
    &&  isDigit(chr)) { # i.e. last 3 chars match /(\D)0(\d)/
        out[-1] = prevChar = chr; # make it \1\2
    } else {
        out.push(prevChar = chr); # just continue building string
    }
}
out.join("");
```

Consider it pseudo-code like javascript, and not tested.

Comment: I found, that this code will work incorrectly on strings like `"\\"`