# String of int and range to array of int (Looking for improvement)

Tags: ruby

First, what I have:

> s = "1,3..5,8"

What I want:

> ["1", "3", "4", "5", "8"]

I found a way with as below

```
r = s.split(/\s?,\s?/)
=> ["10", "12..15", "17", "
r.map do |c|
  if Fixnum === eval(c)
    c
  else
    eval(c).map(&:to_s).flatten
  end
end
=> ["10", "12", "13", "14", "15", "17", "18"]
```

Would there be a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "10,12...15,17" 
s.split(',').map { |n| n['...'] ? Range.new(*n.split('...', 2)).to_a : n}.flatten 
#=> ["10", "12", "13", "14", "15", "17"]
```

Comment: `12...15` in Ruby shouldn't return `15`

Comment: @fl00r true but the original question was written with three-dots and expected to return 15.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use `eval`.

A marginally better way would be:

```
s = "1,3...5,8"
p s.split(',').map { |n|
  if n.scan('...').empty?
    n
  else
    Range.new(*n.split('...', 2)).to_a
  end
}.flatten
# => ["1", "3", "4", "5", "8"]
```

EDIT:
Fixed the code as suggested by @fl00r to work with multiple digit numbers.

Comment: Why would not you use eval? Is there a reason for this or just a personal way of doing it?

Comment: see the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902744/when-is-eval-in-ruby-justified

Comment: what if numbers are two digits? `s=1,3...5,8,11`? And what if ranges are `two-dotted` and `three-dotted`? `s=1..3, 5...7, 20`

Comment: good catch @fl00r, thanks. Regarding the number of dots, the original question asked for two.

Answer (score 2):

```
def magick(str)
  str.split(",").map do |item|
    item.scan(/(\d+)(\.+)(\d+)/)
    if $1
      Range.new($1.to_i, $3.to_i, $2 == "...").to_a
    else
      item.to_i
    end
  end.flatten
end

s1 = "1,3..5,8"
s2 = "1,3...5,8,20,100, 135"
magick(s1)
#=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]
magick(s2)
#=> [1, 3, 4, 8, 20, 100, 135]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
s='1,2..6,10'

s.split(',').map { |e| e.strip.include?('..') ? eval("(#{e}).to_a") : e.to_i }.flatten
```

Comment: i also program in javascript and there eval is evil, don't know about ruby but there must be also drawback's