# How to easily iterate through methods containing number in their name in Ruby, or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While implementing a DBMS similar to [Chadwick database](http://chadwick.sourceforge.net/doc/cwevent.html), I'm encountering lots of similar codes like below (Please refer to the upper link if you think the database design itself is wrong.)

#### Setting values

```
self.away_lineup1_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup1_batter_id
self.away_lineup2_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup2_batter_id
self.away_lineup3_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup3_batter_id
self.away_lineup4_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup4_batter_id
self.away_lineup5_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup5_batter_id
self.away_lineup6_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup6_batter_id
self.away_lineup7_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup7_batter_id
self.away_lineup8_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup8_batter_id
self.away_lineup9_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup9_batter_id
```

or

#### Getting values

```
# Using jbuilder gem.
json.pos2_fielder do
  json.partial! 'players/simple_hash', locals: {data: data.pos2_fielder}
end unless data.pos2_fielder.nil?
json.pos3_fielder do
  json.partial! 'players/simple_hash', locals: {data: data.pos3_fielder}
end unless data.pos3_fielder.nil?
json.pos4_fielder do
  json.partial! 'players/simple_hash', locals: {data: data.pos4_fielder}
end unless data.pos4_fielder.nil?
json.pos5_fielder do
  json.partial! 'players/simple_hash', locals: {data: data.pos5_fielder}
end unless data.pos5_fielder.nil?
json.pos6_fielder do
  json.partial! 'players/simple_hash', locals: {data: data.pos6_fielder}
end unless data.pos6_fielder.nil?
json.pos7_fielder do
  json.partial! 'players/simple_hash', locals: {data: data.pos7_fielder}
end unless data.pos7_fielder.nil?
json.pos8_fielder do
  json.partial! 'players/simple_hash', locals: {data: data.pos8_fielder}
end unless data.pos8_fielder.nil?
json.pos9_fielder do
  json.partial! 'players/simple_hash', locals: {data: data.pos9_fielder}
end unless data.pos9_fielder.nil?
```

Copying and pasting 9 rows of codes aren't really a big deal but I think there could be a better solution for this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary suggestion: use arrays in Ruby and properly normalised database tables. Instead of having `pos2_fielder`, `pos3_fielder`... in one table, you should have a table with `position` property. (I can't say anything more specific as I do not know what your database looks like precisely, aside from "bad").

To answer the literal question:

```
1.upto(9) do |num|
  if player.id === send(:"away_lineup#{num}_batter_id")
    send(:"away_lineup#{num}_batter=", player)
  end
end
```

Comment: I certainly do appreciate your suggestion. (I didn't even know about `send`. Thanks.) If you see [the link](http://chadwick.sourceforge.net/doc/cwevent.html) that I provided, you can grasp the idea of what `lineup#{num}` is.

Comment: `send` is the ultimate swiss army knife for Ruby, as it is even able to invoke private methods on other objects (use with care :p). About the database... again, I am not 100% sure what you are doing, but if you can't choose your DB format, I would rather have a pair of conversion methods that translate the literal database format into something more pleasantly usable. The bottom suggestion should work even if you decide your current way of access is good enough / faster / whatever.

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong with

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].each { |i| eval("self.away_lineup#{i}_batter = player if player.id === away_lineup#{i}_batter_id" }
```

Comment: What's wrong? [`eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902744/when-is-eval-in-ruby-justified), for one thing. :P It is insecure in general (not here), and it is *slow*.

Comment: The question isn't about database design or naming conventions. It's about utilizing ruby to help handle the naming convention the user put in place for whatever reason.

Comment: If you read my answer, there is a solution for the literal question as well - without `eval`, which should be avoided whenever possible, as it invokes the Ruby parser. Even `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` is needlessly verbose and uses more memory than needed.

Comment: yeah, I saw that. I think parts of your answer are good, especially the Primary Suggestion.