# Rails "DateTime.tomorrow" to datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

The title says it all and I'm just curious it this would be somehow possible.

Can you parse the string "DateTime.tomorrow" to the DateTime object `DateTime.tomorrow`? Would that somehow be possible?

I came across this thought while coding, but I solved it another way.

Comment: Is the `DateTime.tomorrow` the only possible input? Or are there other inputs, like `DateTime.today` or `1.week.ago`, that should be handled too?

Comment: @spickermann `DateTime.tomorrow` and `DateTime.now + 1.hour` are possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` for this, but it is usually discouraged, see: [When is `eval` in Ruby justified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902744/when-is-eval-in-ruby-justified)

Comment: how exactly would this turn the string into a datetime object?

Comment: https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval

Comment: eval is evil. dont show people where the gun is, they gonna shoot themselves in their foot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Class.instance_eval()` method. Which will take particular object method as a parameter and return the actual output of the given parameter. In your case `DateTime.instance_eval('DateTime.tomorrow')` will return actual output of `DateTime.tomorrow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```rb
DateTime.now.next_day
```